# Unrecognized platform name macOS,tvOS,iOS,watchOS in PINCatch Pods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

After update pods i have received **Unrecognized platform name** error message in PINCatch Framework.I have try to find solution on google but not getting answer.

Below i have mention pods update logs :

```
Analyzing dependencies
Removing SIOSocket
Removing libjingle_peerconnection
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (3.1.0)
Using BFRImageViewer (1.0.32)
Using Bolts (1.8.4)
Using CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.1)
Installing CocoaLumberjack 3.3.0 (was 3.2.0)
Installing Crashlytics 3.9.0 (was 3.8.6)
Using DACircularProgress (2.3.1)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit 4.27.1 (was 4.25.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit 4.27.1 (was 4.25.0)
Installing FBSDKShareKit 4.27.1 (was 4.25.0)
Using FLAnimatedImage (1.0.12)
Installing Fabric 1.7.0 (was 1.6.12)
Using InstagramKit (3.8)
Using KissXML (5.2.0)
Installing PINCache 3.0.1-beta.6 (was 3.0.1-beta.5)
Installing PINOperation 1.1 (was 1.0.3)
Installing PINRemoteImage 3.0.0-beta.13 (was 3.0.0-beta.11)
Using RSKImageCropper (1.6.3)
Installing TwitterCore 3.0.1 (was 3.0.0)
Installing TwitterKit 3.2.0 (was 3.0.4)
Using UICKeyChainStore (2.1.1)
Using XMPPFramework (3.7.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 13 dependencies from the Podfile and 22 total pods installed.
```

Error Image [image: PINCatch Framework]

**XCODE** Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)
**Deployment Target :** iOS 9
Universal App (iPhone & iPad)

Let me know how to solve this  error ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error in CocoaLumberjack with Xcode8.
I solved it by use Xcode9.
(my Xcode version is 9.0.1)